# Changing the input to a network during a while loop

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand how to use a while loop in TensorFlow. I want to implement a loop where the input to a neural network, is the output (prediction) of the neural network from the previous iteration of the loop.

Now, my neural network (the feedforward part of the while loop) is actually defined elsewhere in my code, as follows:

```
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[None, 2])
hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_placeholder, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
prediction_op = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden_layer, units=2)
```

My while loop is then defined as:

```
num_steps = 10
step_num = 0
init_input = np.array([[0.1, 0.2]], dtype=np.float32)
condition = tf.less(step_num, num_steps)
_, final_prediction_op = tf.while_loop(condition, loop_body, [step_num, init_input])
```

Here, the loop body is:

```
def loop_body(step_num, next_input):
    # What do I do here?
    prediction = prediction_op
    step_num = tf.add(step_num, 1)
    return step_num, prediction
```

To run this while loop, I try:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
final_prediction = sess.run(final_prediction_op)
```

But my issue is, what should I write in the line `# What do I do here?` so that `next_input` is fed as the input to the feedforward network?

I could write the network out again within the loop, but the problem is that I actually have the network defined elsewhere, and do not want to have to copy the same code twice. I want to be able to use the existing network code (my actual network is much much more complicated, and this is just a minimal example). But this network needs `input_placeholder` to be populated with data, and a placeholder is immutable so it cannot be assigned to during the while loop.

Any ideas on how I should solve this? Thanks!